# How to construct and use Angular URL Parameters when URL is in the format: "component/#/?id=..."

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

my current situation is that I have an app with a pre-existing user base. If at all possible I want to avoid breaking their existing links as it would provide the smoothest transition. Only problem is that the previous links are in the format: (server)/viewer/#/?id=12. I tried mocking up an example below:

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-pyczk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Option #1: I can access my **variables** through the link:

https://pyczk.csb.app/viewer/?id=12

And I can make the desired **format** through the link:

https://pyczk.csb.app/viewer/#/?id=12

But I cannot combine the two. While I still have problems with the browser eating some of my characters like "/", I believe I can fix that through a CustomUrlSerializer. Moving past that when using my desired format my app no longer finds/recognizes my values. Is it possible to get access to my values when my URL is in my desired format and if so how?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get that id correctly you should use `HashLocationStrategy` then "/" will not be eaten. In your `app.module` set **second** parameter of `RouterModule` like that:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([], {useHash:true})
```

Then use that code from your example to get id.

```
 this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
   this.queryParamID = params["id"];
 });
```